# SMTP hub or redirector, is this possible?

Tags: linux, exchange, smtp

Situation:

I need to be able to set one SMTP server set of details into some software that sends out emails. However, the software sends emails from many different sender domains, all hosted on different Microsoft tenants. There might be over 10,000 emails going through this per day across all 50+ sender domains combined.

Proposed solution:

I assume what I need is to point the software SMTP settings to a service (let's call it an SMTP HUB) which then redirects the SMTP to the appropriate SMTP server (Microsoft tenant) for the sender address, for each email that comes through. I then simply need to get the Microsoft tenants to trust this SMTP hub as a sending source by IP address (email connector in exchange admin portal).

Knowledge I am missing:

Can you tell me my options for the "SMTP HUB" part of the equation?
I can easily run up a Linux or windows host server to run this, is there a turnkey solution for this?

Thank you in advance, for even reading this far.
Michael A.

Comment: Are your requirements really just that: receiving authenticated mail and relaying? Almost any mail server software can do that. If you need to enforce any non-trivial restrictions, e.g. specifying which domains exactly you want to relay for, you probably want to use Postfix as its configuration syntax for such purposes is clear and well documented.

Comment: How about the anonymous relay on Exchange server?

Comment: I will look into PostFix. Are you sure it will forward to the relevant SMTP server based on sender domain?

Answer (score 0):

How about the Exchange server?
But if you are not familiar with Exchange, it will take a long time to learn it.

Comment: Are you sure Exchange server can do this? Might be more expensive than an alternative, and I have worked with it before, but I didn't realise it could. If so, I wonder if exchange online can do it then, I cannot see a way to set this up there on office 365